# Using Jacoco's offline instrumentation for a multi-module maven project using surefire coverage

Tags: java, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, multi-module, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using Jacoco to calculate coverage on a multi-module project via a final aggregator-module which generates the report. The project's parent pom file has surefire & Jacoco configured as the following:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
      <argLine>${argLine} -Xmx2048m -Duser.timezone=UTC</argLine>
      <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>1200</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
      <forkCount>1</forkCount>
      <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And the project's final reporting module (which inherits all the other modules as dependencies) has Jacoco configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>report-aggregate</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

However i'm getting jacoco warnings relating to tests in some of the modules:

```
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'project-submod1' with 46 classes
[WARNING] Classes in bundle 'project-submod1' do no match with execution data. For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
[WARNING] Execution data for class org/project/submod1/ExampleClass does not match.
```

So i've read I can use either offline instrumentation or setting the classDumpDir to get around this problem: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/classids.html

However i'm unsure of how to accomplish the two options. I've tried to add offline instrumentation tasks to Jacoco in the parent pom file, but I then get complaints that classes are already instrumented. Or if I set  ClassDumpDir for each module, I can't seem to have the final report use each modules' dumped classes, rather than the modified ones...

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do it, but this is what worked for me.

In the parent pom.xml

```
<jacoco.version>0.8.3</jacoco.version>
<surefire.version>3.0.0-M3</surefire.version>

<!-- Stuff Skipped -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
    <classifier>runtime</classifier>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Stuff Skipped -->

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <reportsDirectory>../surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In EACH child pom.xml ( I tried a bunch of variants to avoid editing the children, but none of them seemed to work).  This is based on the configuration for offline jacoco instrumentation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
    <classifier>runtime</classifier>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Stuff Skipped -->

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-instrument</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

The last part is in a reporter module, similar to what is suggested for multi-module jacoco use generally.  However, it includes an call to merge the jacoco.exec results before running the reporter.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>..</directory>
                <include>**/*.exec</include>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>merge</goal>
                <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```